# flextable when saved as pdf using officer prints small ticks

Tags: r, pdf, cpu-word, flextable, officer

See my code

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_doc <- read_docx() 

tb = head(iris, 4)

tb <- flextable(tb)
tb <- width(tb, width = 1.1)

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_flextable(tb, align = 'left')

print(my_doc, target = "file.docx")
```

Word output

[image]

PDF Output > same document saved as pdf

[image]

Comment: How do you create the "PDF output"?

Comment: Using MS Word's save as PDF

Comment: Ah ok, sorry then, I can't reproduce

Comment: You're on Linux?
How would you save this as pdf?

Comment: I am on a mac. (For PDF I would use a Rmd file but I am not sure it's relevant here)

Comment: I can reproduce this on my Windows machine. Interestingly, it seems to only occur when border width=2 (which is used by the default `theme_booktabs` here). Applying a thinner OR wider width (e.g. 1 or 3) doesn't trigger it.

Comment: This issue can arise with tables created inside MS Word too. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1504963/artefacts-on-table-borders-in-adobe-pdf-reader) for an example. I suspect it's not a flextable issue.